# Error while trying to view the attribute table

Tags: arcmap, attribute-table

I have a shapefile which displays fine in ArcMap. When I view the attribute table I get the following error. However the same shapefile loads fine and can view its attribute table to in QGIS. Any ideas ??

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I have had this it has usually been due to an invalid field name.  The biggest culprit is a comma in the field name.  QGIS is not bothered by this but ESRI is.  So check your attribute table field names for anything dodgy.  Spaces seem to be OK but I try to avoid them as well.

Comment: Thanks .Yes I did figure out that this error comes when the shapefile name itself is long and has " _" in it .

Comment: The web help has a good section on feature class naming at http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002200000002000000.htm but I could not quickly locate an equivalent page describing the rules for shapefile naming